# can't reboot router via curl cron

Tags: curl, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to use curl to set up a cron to reboot my WD N900 Router on a regular basis.

Using Chrome's developer tools, when I login to the the router via its WebGUI, it brings me to "authentication.cgi". Here's its essential components copied as a curl (bash):

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.1/authentication.cgi' \
  -H 'Cookie: QPYVIXOAZD=admin; uid=lseKLfq8zc' \
  --data-raw 'USERNAME=admin&DIGEST=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

The critical component is the cookie entry, of which the uid is unique for that particular login.

To reboot the router, I then go through several pages, eventually getting to "service.cgi". Here's its essential components copied as a curl (bash):

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.1/service.cgi' \
  -H 'Cookie: QPYVIXOAZD=admin; uid=lseKLfq8zc' \
  --data-raw 'EVENT=REBOOT'
```

For a successful reboot via curl from service.cgi, the cookie uid must be the same as that in authentication.cgi. Otherwise, it doesn't reboot, and states "Authorization failure."

How can I get this to work without first obtaining a cookie via a WebGUI login (which defeats the purpose of curl)?

I tried to set up a cookie jar (curl -c /tmp/cookie-jar.txt ....) and remove the "Cookie:..." line, which resulted in another "Authorization failure" as well as an empty cookie file save for this:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
```

I also tried "curl - u myusername:mypassword" (with and without --digest or --noauth options) to no avail ("authorization failure").

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:** When I curl authentication.cgi with my username:password:

```
curl --user admin:XXXXXXXXXX 'http://192.168.1.1/authentication.cgi'
```

I get this type of response:

```
{"uid": "9auO5hcbq8", "CHALLENGE": "bdce6395-f46b-4306-a61b-1ec2de1bf7d5"}
```

Can this information be used somehow? I pasted that uid into the Cookie in my previous curl for service.cgi, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

{"uid": "9auO5hcbq8", "CHALLENGE": "bdce6395-f46b-4306-a61b-1ec2de1bf7d5"}

> Can this information be used somehow?

Use them (at least the uid) in your subsequent service request cookie

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, uid=9auO5hcbq8; QPYVIXOAZD=admin;);
```

I'm not sure what you should do with this:

```
CHALLENGE=bdce6395-f46b-4306-a61b-1ec2de1bf7d5;
```

Maybe include it as a cookie.  Or maybe a post field.

When you say:

> For a successful reboot via curl from service.cgi, the cookie uid must
> be the same as that in authentication.cgi. Otherwise, it doesn't
> reboot, and states "Authorization failure."

I interpret this to mean first you need to get a currently valid cookie value. 
Where you do the `authentication.cgi'` request then use the `uid` in the subsequent `service.cgi` request.

The thing I think may be problematic is the cookie file is empty.  It is possible that no cookie is being returned in the response. But I have found the curl cookie box to be problematic.  So I handle cookies on my own.

For me, I use PHP scripts to troubleshoot problems like this.

What I would do is run a cron job to run a PHP script to do this.
If you do not know PHP, I will write it for you.

The cron job would look like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/<user>/backup/reboot.php
```

I really hope that this curl command worked for you or this answer is moot:

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.1/authentication.cgi' \
  -H 'Cookie: QPYVIXOAZD=admin; uid=lseKLfq8zc' \
  --data-raw 'USERNAME=admin&DIGEST=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

This would be my first step where this is the reboot.php given the above cron job setting.  This is based on my basic curl troubleshooting procedure. I have been in your position many times.  I developed this over ten years ago.

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/plain');    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.1/authentication.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'QPYVIXOAZD=admin; uid=lseKLfq8zc');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'USERNAME=admin&DIGEST=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
var_export($response);

echo "\nheader out: " . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
?>
```

Comment: The curl command for authentication.cgi that you asked about - which I copied from Chrome's developer's tools - is what appears AFTER I login to the router via the WebGUI.  I then take that Cooke uid and paste it into the curl for service.cgi, and the router reboots.  I assume that running the reboot.php you wrote (thanks!!) is supposed to produce a cookie with the uid that was specified? Working on that assumption, I ran reboot.php, followed immediately by the curl for service.cgi (with same uid as reboot.php), but it again came up with "Authorization failure."

Comment: Tried your update suggestion -still no luck. Is there some command to see what/if cookies exist for my router (192.168.1.1) after I've initiated your php script?

Comment: Developer's tools in Chrome and Firefox show that the only time a uid cookie is made is when I log in to the router via a web browser. The admin Cookie is always there.

Comment: Do you have a link to the WD N900 API documentation that explains how to do a reset?  As is, I can only guess and that is not going very well.  When I searched for documentation I got:  Support for this product has ended and is no longer available

Comment: There is a manual available somewhere online, but it doesn't get into working with the router on a command-line level. The router has telnet capabilities (no SSH) which is initialized via a hidden web page. However, the telnet stops working after a short amount of time (30 minutes?), and one has to again go to the hidden web page and restart it, making it impractical for my use.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the my router's web pages produces cookies via Javascript, which curl can't read or produce. I'll probably have to look into a text-based browser whose actions I can integrate into a script which would later use curl (or maybe wget).